# physical path in silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I need to get physical path in silverlight. I'm using WCF service, I created one folder called 'Myfolder'. So I need to get the path of myfolder Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight doesn't allow direct access to the file system. However you can take advantage of Isolated Storage to read and write files on the client side. [Here](http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/#example) is a tutorial for that.

If you need access to a folder in the web application that is hosting your Silverlight app, use your service. Once you are in your OperationContract method, or even if you leverage the WebClient to make an AJAX style request, you can access the file system *on* *the* *server* but remember that is a different machine than your Silverilght client with the exception of when you do development (or browse your app on the server).

Comment: Actually you can access the file system but you need to use the OpenFileDialog.